# linux + how to split ISO file to separate pieces

Tags: linux, rhel, tar, iso, split

we are using the following ISO file for rhel upgrade

```
4.2G    RHEL-7.6.iso
```

since we have problem to copy this ISO file between WIN to Linux machine

and that because sometime network problem cause ISO file to be corrupted

we are thinking if it possible to perform ISO file split as can be on tar.gz file with `split` command

example

```
RHEL-7.6.iso.part
RHEL-7.6.iso.part
RHEL-7.6.iso.part
RHEL-7.6.iso.part
```

so each file will be `~1G` and by this transferring of the ISO will be more better

but after searching in google we not found option for ISO split , but I also want to ask here to be sure that I not miss an option to do split of ISO file

reference -

https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/split-and-join-targz-file-linux/

https://www.tecmint.com/split-large-tar-into-multiple-files-of-certain-size/

Comment: What have you tried and didn't work as expected?

Comment: Instead of searching on the web, have you tried looking at `man split`?

Comment: now I found that - https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-can-i-split-a-file-to-several-smaller-pieces/ , is it also fit for rhel.iso files?

Comment: yael, in the linked post, all you need is the `split` and the `cat` commands you see into the beginning of this question. Edit the size you want, files will be named in the right order for `cat *` them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used google fu and found this

```
split -b [size of split pieces] [file to split] [split file prefix]
```

https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-can-i-split-a-file-to-several-smaller-pieces/